# How to use TestFlight to release the adhoc version app?

Tags: ios, testflight, fastlane, adhoc

Is there a way to have both the app store version and the TestFlight version installed at the same time on one iPhone? Can we release the ad-hoc version of the test app via the TestFlight? How to use FastLane to publish a test ad-hoc version of the app in the TestFlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have different bundleID (mean different app) to install at same time. Other wise app will replace existing app no matter what process you used to download application.